# Convert encoded android:versionCode to Integer

Tags: android

I have an AndroidManifest.xml from an APK, and the versionCode is given as

```
A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0xd6bfc0
```

The Hex value mentioned comes to 14073792 in Int using straightforward conversion, and it seems highly unlikely there have been those many versions of the app.

Is there some special procedure for converting Android versionCode to Int?

Comment: versionCode is just an integer and the upgrade mechanism works as long as it is monotonically increasing across package versions. No need to go in +1 increments or anything. 14073792 is perfectly fine integer for one particular version.

Comment: I was wondering what (type 0x10) means

Comment: It's just int type. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#TYPE_INT_DEC